# Problems writing/reading an vector of Objects to a file

Tags: c++, vector, fstream

I got this problem, where I want to make a Devicelist, which I do with a vector of Devices. But I can't make it read/write correctly.

This is my functions:

```
#include "Devicelist.h"

bool Devicelist::AddDevice(const char *deviceName, char *type)
{
    Device tempDevice(deviceName, type, ++id_);
    Devicelist_.push_back(tempDevice);
    return true;
}

bool Devicelist::deleteDevice(const char *deviceName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Devicelist_.size(); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(deviceName, Devicelist_[i].getName()) == 0)
        {
            Devicelist_.erase(Devicelist_.begin() + i);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "No Device found with that Devicename." << endl;
            return false;
        }
    }
}

bool Devicelist::SaveToFile()
{
    //remove("Devices.dat");

    ofstream SaveFile("Devices.dat", ios::out | ios::binary);

    if (!SaveFile)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        return false;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Devicelist_.size(); i++)
        SaveFile.write((const char *)(&Devicelist_[i]), sizeof(Devicelist_[i]));


    SaveFile.close();
    return true;
}

bool Devicelist::LoadFromFile()
{
    ifstream LoadFile("Devices.dat", ios::in | ios::binary);

    if (!LoadFile)
    {
        cerr << "File could not be opened." << endl;
        return false;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < Devicelist_.size(); i++)
        LoadFile.read((char *)(&Devicelist_[i]), sizeof(Devicelist_[i]));


    LoadFile.close();
    return true;
}

Device Devicelist::findDevice(const char *deviceName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Devicelist_.size(); i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(deviceName, Devicelist_[i].getName()) == 0)
            return Devicelist_[i];
        else
            cout << "Couldn't find device." << endl;
    }
}
```

And this is my main:

```
#include "Devicelist.h"

void main()
{
    Devicelist list; 
    list.AddDevice("Lampe3", "Lampe");
    list.AddDevice("Lampe4", "Lampe");
    list.SaveToFile();


    Devicelist list2;
    list2.LoadFromFile();

    Device lampe = list2.findDevice("Lampe");

    cout << lampe.getName() << endl;
    cout << lampe.getID() << endl;
    cout << lampe.getType() << endl;
}
```

Can anyone see what my problem is?

Thanks in advance!

## Edit1:

My .h-file for Devicelist is:

```
#ifndef DEVICELIST_H
#define DEVICELIST_H 

#include "Device.h"
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

class Devicelist
{
public:
    Devicelist();
    bool SaveToFile();
    bool LoadFromFile();
    bool AddDevice(const char *deviceName, char *type);
    bool deleteDevice(const char *deviceName);
    Device findDevice(const char *devicename);
private:
    vector<Device> Devicelist_;
    int id_;
};

#endif
```

This is my Device .h-file:

```
#ifndef DEVICE_H
#define DEVICE_H 

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#define DNAME_SIZE 33

using namespace std;

class Device
{
public:
    Device(const char *devicename = "Default", char *type = "type", int id = 0);
    const char *getName();
    int getID();
    int getType();
private:
    char deviceName_[DNAME_SIZE];
    int id_;
    int type_;
};

#endif
```

And Device .cpp-file:

```
#include "Device.h"

Device::Device(const char *deviceName, char *type, int id)
{
    strncpy_s(deviceName_, deviceName, DNAME_SIZE);

    if (type == "Lampe")
        type_ = 1;
    else if (type == "Roegalarm")
        type_ = 2;
    else if (type == "Tyverialarm")
        type_ = 3;
    else
    {
        type_ = 0;
        cout << "Type does not exists." << endl;
    }

    id_ = id;
}

const char *Device::getName()
{
    return deviceName_;
}

int Device::getID()
{
    return id_;
}

int Device::getType()
{
    return type_;
}
```

The problem is when I try to read view what's saved in the file, this is the output:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqWdm.jpg

Comment: **What is** the problem that you're facing?

Comment: Are you getting a compiler error?

Comment: Please post `DeviceList.h`.

Comment: If you give us a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org/), I expect that we can solve it in a minute or two.

Comment: Also, what is `Device`?  My suspicion is that you're saving a non-POD type in the same way as a POD type (just doing a memory copy), and that is just plain wrong.

Comment: Include the output in the question. A link to an externally hosted image of the textual output is just ridiculous.  (Links are a bad idea generally because one day that link will die, making the question useless for future users of this site).

Comment: @Thisen Don't forget to delete the old one :) ...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here in the `LoadFromFile` function, I think:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Devicelist_.size(); i++)
    LoadFile.read((char *)(&Devicelist_[i]), sizeof(Devicelist_[i]));
```

The `DeviceList` is empty, or has the wrong size.
You could write something similar as in `AddDevice`:

```
Device tempDevice();
LoadFile.read((char *)(&tempDevice), sizeof(tempDevice));
Devicelist_.push_back(tempDevice);
```

but the size (how many devices) of the file needs to be known.

As mentioned in a comment, this works only if `Device` doesn't have pointers to other objects for example. It should be a POD (Plain Old Data) object.

An elegant solution would be to implement streaming operators on `Device`

Comment: `sizeof(tempDevice)` should probably `sizeof(Device)`, just to avoid confusions. Though _'serializing'_ data this way, migh tbe pretty bad advice!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ `sizeof(tempDevice)` works with most compilers, I use it because it's easier. Yes, there are better solutions, I just added a suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to to have `Device::StoreToFile` write the number of devices before writing out each device.  This will enable your `Device::LoadFromFile` to know how many device instances to read from the file.

I highly recommend you do not write a class or structure bit for bit to the file.  If your class or struct has any advanced data structures, such as `std::string` or `std::vector`, you can't write them in binary.  They may use pointers to memory, which will not be the same when you load them.

Here is a better solution:
1. Pass a buffer of uint8_t to the load and store methods.
2. The methods load from the buffer or store into the buffer (append).
3. The caller reads or writes the buffer to file.
4. The class also has a "size on file" method that returns the space occupied on a file, which may be different than the structure size.

Also search the web for "boost::serialization".